# Checking if date is greater than today

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying out a Jquery to confirm if date selected is equal to today or greater than.
If i select today, it return it as the day selected is less than today. Selecting previous day works well but selecting today returns less than. Any tip.

```
var firstRepaymentDate = new Date($('#First_Repayment_Date').val());
                var today = new Date();
                if (firstRepaymentDate.getTime() < today.getTime()) {
                    alert('The First Repayment Date Can only Be Today Or Future Date');
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: `new Date()` will include the current time not just the date. Try `today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` to set the time to midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that `new Date()` will include the current time as well. You'll need to remove that time component with `today.setHours(0,0,0,0)` for the comparison to be correct.

Also, `setHours()` returns the underlying value like `getTime()` so you can do

```js
var firstRepaymentDate = new Date($('#First_Repayment_Date').val());
var today = new Date();
if (firstRepaymentDate.getTime() < today.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    alert('The First Repayment Date Can only Be Today Or Future Date');
    return false;
}
```

In response to the comment about adding 20 days:

This is a little more detailed but is fairly easy.

```js
var today = new Date();
var plus20Days = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 20));
```

again you can then use `setHours()` to reset the time component.

Comment: Good idea, didn't think about "resetting" the hour

Comment: @phuzi, Thank you for this. What if i want to check if the date selected is at least 20days greater than today?

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` considers time too, not only the date. I think the easiest way to achieve this is to compare years, months and days by using respectively `getFullYear() , getMonth() , getDate().`

Check all the methods that manipulate js Date here
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date